# Restore default color codes in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, seaborn

I called `sns.set(color_codes=True)` when I was testing code using an example from the docs, and now I can't seem to turn it off. 'r' and 'b' are returning red and blue from the default [seaborn color palette](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html) rather than the bright matplotlib colors (close to [1,0,0] and [0,0,1]) as they normally do.

This code:

```
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
lut = dict(zip(iris.columns,['r','r','b','b']))
g = sns.clustermap(iris,
    col_colors=iris.columns.map(lut),col_cluster=False,cmap='bwr')
```

Gives me:
[image]

But what I expect is for the red and blue of the column color labels to be the same as those of the colormap. I have tried (each of these individually):

```
sns.set(color_codes=False)
##
sns.set()
##
sns.reset_orig()
##
sns.color_palette(palette=None)
sns.set(color_codes=True)
```

As well as shutting down and restarting Python, to no avail. How do I fix this?

Comment: you tried [`sns.reset_defaults()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.reset_defaults.html)?

Comment: Ok it didn't work by itself. It may have been the combination of calling this and restarting python that fixed it. But I'm not sure as I can't exactly reproduce the issue anymore; restarting python now fixes it alone. Thanks!

Comment: In the future if you want different plotting style without saving it use `with sns.set(color_codes=True)`, so the setting is only changed for the following indented block