# Avoid seaborn influencing matplotlib plots, none of the solutions work

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I know this question was already asked and answered (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54885636/avoid-seaborn-influencing-matplotlib-plots) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25393936/how-can-i-use-seaborn-without-changing-the-matplotlib-defaults)), but the answers are not working for me.

I'm first plotting some figure with matplotlib and then one with seaborn. After I imported seaborn in the cell I'm plotting something with it, it changes the color of all following matplotlib plot, and the previous plots too if I'm rerunning the cell. This is very annoying. See the color difference.

[image]

[image]

- I tried `plt.style.use('default')` at the beginning of my notebook, it doesn't work.
- I tried `# reset RC params to original sns.reset_orig()` at the beginning and after my cell, doesn't work either.
- I tried `import seaborn.apionly as sns`, and there are no such module...
- I tried:`# Now, reset Matplotlib color cycle to default plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = plt.rcParamsDefault['axes.prop_cycle']`, same.

What can I do ?

I'm plotting the matplotlib figure with the base color (b, m, c, k, ...). This is my code for my seaborn figure:

```
    # When you import seaborn the default styling is changed.
import seaborn as sns

## Reset Seaborn to default Matplotlib settings
sns.reset_orig()

# transform the numpy array into panda data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(data_T)

# Replace the name of the column with labels defines above
df.columns = labels

# Create pairplot with only the lower triangular part
g = sns.set(style="ticks")
g = sns.pairplot(df,
                 corner=True,
                 diag_kind='hist',
                 plot_kws = dict(marker="+", linewidth=1),
                 vars = labels, # labels
                 hue = "pwv [mm]") # variable in 3rd dimension
                # , palette = colors) # varslist of variable names



# remove the 3rd dimension in the histogram
g.map_diag(sns.histplot, hue=None, color = '0.4')

# palette dict or seaborn color palette. Set of colors for mapping the hue variable. If a dict, keys should be values in the hue variable.

plt.savefig('triqngle_plot02.png')
```

Comment: I just tried, not working either...

Comment: Did you read the comments below [Restore default color codes in seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55861587/restore-default-color-codes-in-seaborn) about using `with sns.set(color_codes=True)` around the part that calls seaborn? Could your create a fully stand-alone simple example? Now it is unclear which way you use to color the plots. WIth a colormap? With some fixed named color? ...?

Comment: Which Seaborn version are you using? Does `matplotlib.rc_file_defaults()` work? According to [github issue #554](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/pull/554), only the shorthand color codes are changed (like `'b', 'm', ...`) and only if you call `sns.set()` or something similar. Just importing seaborn without calling `sns.set()` shouldn't change matplotlib. `sns.reset_defaults()` should undo these changes. Please include fully reproducible test code.

Comment: I have Seaborn version: 0.13.0 ! Thank you it worked !! I had #g = sns.set(style="ticks") in my code and removing it made it work ! Can you write this as an answer please ?

Comment: `set.set()` has now been replaced by `sns.set_theme()`. If you don't want to change the color codes, but do want the other seaborn defaults, you can use `sns.set_theme(color_codes=False)`.  Note that you should remove the `g = `, as `sns.set()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: You can safely delete the question, as it doesn't include reproducible code.

Comment: Why deleting when other people might have the same problem and find no solution ? I wouldn't mind proving the code but it's unnecessarily long et complicated, I could procure a example with the mistake ...

Comment: Now I added my code for my seaborn plot with the mistake, you can add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll add my remarks with `#-->` into the code

```py
# When you import seaborn the default styling is changed.
#--> Well, no, importing seaborn doesn't change the default styling
import seaborn as sns

## Reset Seaborn to default Matplotlib settings
sns.reset_orig()
#--> Not necessary, as the default styling didn't change

# transform the numpy array into panda data frame
#--> (data_T wasn't definded...)
df = pd.DataFrame(data_T)

# Replace the name of the column with labels defines above
#--> (the labels weren't definded...)
#--> (you can also add the column names in `df = pd.DataFrame(data_T, columns=labels))`)
df.columns = labels


# Create pairplot with only the lower triangular part
g = sns.set(style="ticks")
#--> Well, here you ask seaborn to change the default styling
#--> You can use `sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=False)` if you
#        don't want to change matplotlib's standard colors
#--> (You shouldn't assign the result of `sns.set`, it has no return value)


g = sns.pairplot(df,
                 corner=True,
                 diag_kind='hist',
                 plot_kws = dict(marker="+", linewidth=1),
                 vars = labels, # labels
                 hue = "pwv [mm]") # variable in 3rd dimension
                # , palette = colors) # varslist of variable names


# remove the 3rd dimension in the histogram
g.map_diag(sns.histplot, hue=None, color='0.4')

#--> here you could call `sns.reset_orig()`

plt.savefig('triqngle_plot02.png')
```

Comment: Providing the definition of data_T is useless since it's my personal data set stored on my computer and the definition of the labels is irrelevant to the problem here, otherwise, thanks :)

Comment: Well, your code doesn't show the problem with matplotlib, it just creates a seaborn plot where you explicitly called `sns.set()` to change the defaults. 'data_T' is necessary to create a reproducible example. Also, its dimensions have a large effect on the plot.  It is recommended to provide simple dummy data, just enough to reproduce the problem.  Here, e.g. `data_T = np.random.rand(20, 3)` and `labels = ['a', 'b', 'c']` could be tried, together with a dummy `"pwv [mm]"` (which also shows whether it is categorical or not).

Comment: I understand, I tried to reproduce a dummy example with simple seaborn and Matplotlib figures, but of course the error didn't show up because I didn't write the problematic line in my dummy example. Then I guess I could have written a dummy example wrong on purpose afterwards but idk...